# How to track file modifications in unix?

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu

I want to ask you, how I can track file events (e.g. create, update, delete, etc.) on unix using c?

Comment: For Linux you might like to read here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Perhaps use SVN/GIT/Mercurial?

Comment: I need write my own implementation of tracking file events, able to send information to server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inotify`.

From the man page:

> The `inotify` API provides a mechanism for monitoring file system events. `Inotify` can be used to monitor individual files, or to monitor directories.  When a directory is monitored, `inotify` will return events for the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.

Essentially you create an `inotify` instance with `inotify_init` which returns an fd, then add a number of watches with `inotify_add_watch`. You can then `select` on the `fd` and will get notified of any changes relating to the watches you have made.

Answer (score -1):

Unix native package do not provide anything to maintain file versions.
you can use SVN unix tool to maintain versions.